# Extrema of Multi.Varb.Function when Hessian=0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, hessian-matrix

Given is the function $f(x,y)=(y^2-x^2)(y^2-2x^)$
After calculating everything we get the only Critical Point at $P(0,0)$
Plugging it into all the Second Order Partial Derivatives we get the Hessian with only $0$ entries at every Point.
So now there are possibilitis to classify Extremas if Determinant $H=0$ e.g using special Lines/Planes to set up more information but is there a way to do the classification with all entries $0$?

Comment: is this $$f(x,y)=(y^2-x^2)(y^2-2x^)?$$

Comment: use the second derivative test

Comment: yes it is.second derivative test is inconclusive if all entries are zero

Comment: what is the value of your discriminant?

Comment: Zero, since all entries of the Hessian Matrix are Zero

Comment: then you must consider higher derivatives

Comment: Could u give me a hint on what i need to consider at higher derivatives

Comment: at first fix your $\LaTeX$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **five** critical points, namely $(0,0)$, $(1,\pm\sqrt{3/2})$, and $(2,\pm2)$. The latter four can be classified by means of the Hessian. The origin is a degenerate critical point, but we can analyze it using the factorization
$$f(x,y)=(y-x)(y+x)(y^2-2x)\ .\tag{1}$$
The function $f$ is zero along the lines $y=x$ and  $y=-x$, as well as on the parabola $y^2-2x=0$. All three of these curves go through the origin, and $f$ changes sign whenever the moving point $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ crosses one of them. (Example: On one side of the line $y=x$ the factor $(y-x)$ in $(1)$ is $>0$, and on the other side of this line the factor $(y-x)$ is $<0$. All other factors in $(1)$ keep their sign when this line is crossed.) It follows that $f(0,0)=0$, and $f$ assumes both signs in the immediate neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Whether you want to call $(0,0)$ a saddle point is up to you. Some people would call it a monkeys saddle.

Comment: thanks very helpful!

Comment: ok guess I was a little to quick. I got the idea to solve problems like this but im confused with verification. How did you get the sign changes? by noting the sign changes in y=x ; y=-x ? And could i somehow note the sign changes without factorization? e.g some sequences in a neighborhood of (0,0). (Might be a silly question but i really need to school my inuition in those matters)